# Accidentally made blueberry wine - but is it safe?

Tags: fruit

I bought some bottled blueberries, and after eating most of them left the remainder in their liquid (a light syrup). After several months in the cupboard it's fizzy, alcoholic, and quite pleasant tasting... but is it safe to drink?

Answer (score 4):

**Most likely**

Wine will never spoil so that it is dangerous to humans, but that is assuming that it actually fermented to a decent alcohol level. Alcohol will kill most bacterias and preserve the liquid. However if the bottle was open, keep an eye out for bugs and other things that can have fallen into it. Baring that it should be perfectly safe to drink, or at least as safe as any liquid containing alcohol can be.

Comment: Wine will not spoil, but juice can, before alcohol level is up. Who knows what bacteria produced before they died? Probably nothing to worry about. But maybe. Risk is really low, but real.

Answer (score 3):

Impossible to know based on the data supplied.
Consume at your own risk.  Likely its fine, but its impossible to give the right answer.

Comment: What information could I supply that would help?

Comment: Microbial analysis.  My point is that nasty stuff can grow in fruit juices and even beer wort.  If a non harmful microbe gets the upper hand and lowers the pH and make some ethanol then the nasty stuff tends to not be a problem.  The point here is that you just don't know if those two things happened.  I'd still be willing to taste it.  I am just saying the answer to the question can't come from some guy like me telling "its OK" over the internet.

Comment: Fair enough, but the same is true of any homebrew, right?

Comment: Absolutely the same is true for homebrew.  I guess my answer is just sort of my distaste of those that rely on the mantra "No pathogens can live in beer."  That is true, but they most certainly can live and take up residence in wort/must that hasn't been fermented.

Comment: @brewchez and even if they're dead when yeast produced alcohol, there is possibility they left some nasty stuff behind. Slight one, but real.